# How to validate file field in codeigniter through jquery/ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the big form for submission with multiple fields. This form is validated by codeigniter at the backend, and jquery/Ajax at the frontend. It works perfect.
But now I want add field for file uploading in this form. The problem is how to validate this file field in codeigniter through Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Dear first of all you have to add form attribute as `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag then when you going to insert into table in model at that time check like this:

```
if (trim($_FILES['imagename']['name'])!='')

  /*insert*/

}
else {
    return 'please select image';
}
```